# wordpress: Auto generate numbers for a field

Tags: wordpress

This is my first question since I couldn't find an answer anywhere.
I am using a wordpress theme which has a custom post type, and there is a field called ID.

I am trying to auto generate number values for this field.

for example when I add a new post, the ID field will have its value set automatically.
I guess I need a counter to do this so each new post will have its unique value for the ID field.

any help? please

Thank you

Comment: Use the post ID - a value that's already set and unique.

Comment: But I would like to start the numbering from 250 or 300. is there away to do that ?

Comment: Simplest method: Add 250 to the post ID.

Comment: I'm not really an expert. you can say i'm a NOOB lol, Can you please tell me how to do this ?